# Image from URL in TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsstring, nsdata

I have a issue with placing my image in the tablview. Now Everything seemes to be coded right since I recieve no errors or warning messages and when I watch the dump while running in the simulator you can clearly see it loading the images as you scroll up and down and in the cell itself all the content is pushed over like its ready for that image but still no go!

So here is the line of code I am using -

NOTE: "avatarsURL" is a MutableArray and if I try to change it to anything else but it gives me a flag warning saying incompatible pointer to string.....

In this header "avatarsURL" is a MutableArray but is = to a NSString from within another .H file of a NSDictionary.

```
 NSString *imageurl = [avatarsURL objectAtIndex:0]; 
 NSLog(@"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1268205919/iDD_normal.png");   
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   
URLWithString:imageurl]]; 
UIImage *tableImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData]; 

[cell.imageView setImage:tableImage]; 
//cell.imageView.image = tableImage;//Another Method I was trying but same thing
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(75,75);   
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize); 
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.2, 0.1, imageSize.width, imageSize.height); 
[tableImage drawInRect:imageRect]; 
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And I used a Known http:// .image for testing purposes so I know that it is not the server or the actual call out which is JSON request

Any suggestions would be ver much appreciated! I am completely lost without any dumps, errors or warnings. Hope to hear from someone soon,

Thank you !!!

Original NSLog dump
I can only show Two Links because I am a new member and spam reasons...but you get the idea This could go on and on and on forever!!! it loads up around 30 to start then just show the rest as you scroll!

```
2011-05-29 22:02:37.940 ThemeCatcher[6463:207]    
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1268205919/iDD_normal.png
2011-05-29 22:02:37.957 ThemeCatcher[6463:207] 
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1268205919/iDD_normal.png
```

and with the NSLog provided below it does the same things but instead of the link it says NULL

```
2011-05-29 22:08:04.368 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.369 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.370 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.371 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.372 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.373 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.374 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
2011-05-29 22:08:04.375 ThemeCatcher[6503:207] (null)
```

UPDATE!~!!!

AWNSER

EXPLANATION~ In your NSDictionary Make sure you use this below as user is a dictionary of objects.....

In One SubClass Make a

NSObject {

NSDictionary *YourDictionary

}

Then

-(NSString *)yourStrings;

Then in the .m file create your Dictionary of strings like shown below for your users avatars!

```
-(NSString*)avatarURL {

return [[contents objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];



}
```

Now This is How I added the image to the cell!!!!  Happy Coding at least now there is some type of solution to this on the WEB!!!

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[(Tweet*)[avatarsURL    
 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]avatarURL]];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
// NSLog(@"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1268205919/iDD_normal.png");//Done Loging  
 UIImage *tableImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
 [cell.imageView setImage:tableImage]; 
 cell.imageView.image = tableImage ;
 CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(45,45);  
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize); 
 CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.2, 0.1, imageSize.width, imageSize.height); 
 [tableImage drawInRect:imageRect]; 
  cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: "In this header "avatarsURL" is a MutableArray but is = to a NSString from within another .H file of a NSDictionary." makes no sense to me... can you rephrase that? and what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Can you change the NSLog statement to read NSLog(@"%@", imageurl);      This will show you if your URL is passed to iniWithContentsOfURL correctly.

Comment: Hello chris. When I change it from what I had to this It does the same this in the dump which I will show above. seems to be working I am lost! Felipe : I know it is very confusing but works for all other items... To clarify that statement I have 2 subclasses handling this ... One is a NSObject With a NSDictionary in that dictionary I have added a NSString - avatarURL then in my "ViewController" I import that .h and it becomes a MutableArray but is = that avatarURL NSString in the Dictionary which like I said is working for all the other parses being called

Comment: Still no solution =( Ive tried just about everything

Comment: OK OK I got it working! For any of you that read this and want to know how I have updated the Page with the correct solution. ESPECIALLY if you are using MGTwitterEngine! WOW is that a task...now if your trying to go this route and only want to display a few tweets thats fine but any more then 20 I would Asynchronize with the images